# Let PI ask a new IP address every time the ethernet cable is plugged in

Tags: ethernet

I'm trying to let my Raspberry Pi ask for a new IP address everytime an ethernet cable is plugged in. So it doesn't only ask for an IP address when the Pi is booting.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the Pi as such.  You may be better off asking in a general networking forum.

Comment: Although I've seen even electronics suppliers using this misnomer, an ethernet jack [isn't really an RJ45](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#8P8C), so for the purpose of nit-picking I've edited.  P.S. have a look into [`ifplugd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ifplugd), which is installed and run as an init service by default on raspbian, if you want to do this.  As joan points out though, this is a little off topic here and would probably fly better on the [Unix & Linux Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: i'm not sure but try setting `auto eth0` `allow-hotplug eth0` `iface eth0 inet dhcp`. I am not sure if it will work but try it out **unless you aren't connected to pi via SSH**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me: 
Just go to `/etc/network/interfaces` 

Edit interfaces with `sudo nano interfaces` 

`auto eth0 allow-hotplug eth0 iface eth0 inet dhcp`

DONE! =)

I'll mark this as the answer in two days, because then it can.

Comment: this look more like a renewal of your IP. did you get a différent IP when on same network ? (if that was your intend)

Comment: I also understood the question in the way that a fresh IP address was desired (for some reason). Good that it worked out anyway.

Comment: Archemar, that was not the intention. It just needs to ask for an IP, it does not need to have new one. Thanks for all the help guys!